# In LibGDX, change the fixture definition while the program is running

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d

I am currently using the Box2D Engine in LibGDX for my new game.
Is there a way to change the settings of the fixture definition while the program is running?

Kr UbuLin

Answer (score 1):

`FixtureDef` is just prototype that create `Fixture` for physics body, I think you want to change fixture of body at runtime.

Yes you can, suppose I want to change density of body that is already created.

```
Array<Fixture> fixtures=body.getFixtureList();
for (Fixture fixture:fixtures)
    fixture.setDensity(2);
```

Then you need to call `body.resetMassData();` to apply changes.

One more option you can destroy fixture of body and re-create with different configuration.